# Unable to import numpy in Jupyter (instead getting: NameError: 'True' is not defined)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, import, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook is suddenly unable to import numpy. I have used the standard code to import the package and the following error code is returned.

Using atom, the import works fine. Jupyter notebook, however, has suddenly stopped being able to do this.

```
    import numpy as np
```

#### this is what is returned by Jupyter Notebook

```
    NameError                                 
    Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
    ----> 1 import numpy as np

    ~/numpy.py in <module>
         99    "execution_count": 11,
         100    "metadata": {
     --> 101     "scrolled": true
         102    },
         103    "outputs": [

    NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `numpy.py` in your working directory?

Comment: indeed I do, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
~/numpy.py in <module>
```

Like Chirs said, it seems you have a `numpy.py` file in your home directory.